# Best way to add to a value in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

Im having an issue with code for a banking system. I have a list called "bank" where all of the key value pairs are in the format name:amount ie. (John : 115.6 , Carla : 40 , Sam :67). I want to be able to take a "deposit" and add it to the total value in a given pair so: John : 115.6 + a deposit of 45 makes John : 160.6 . So whats the best way to get the sum of a value and input amount and update the dictionary?

```py
if username in log_in:
    if log_in.values() == True:
        print(username)
    if amount < 0 and bank.values() - amount < 0:
        return False
    if amount > 0:
        bank_update = bank.values() + amount
        bank.update(bank_update)
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Comment: `bank['John'] += 45`.  I suggest backing up a few steps and reading a tutorial chapter about Python dictionaries; your code suggests to me that you're copying bits and pieces of things you've seen elsewhere without understanding how they work, and you're very likely to keep having difficulties if you don't slow down and take the time to learn the basics.

Comment: `bank.values()` and `bank.update()` doesn't work the way you think. You need to read more about dictionaries and the fundamentals.

Comment: (John : 115.6 , Carla : 40 , Sam :67) is not Python

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
bank = {"John" : 115.6, "Carla" : 40, "Sam" : 67}

username = input()
amount = int(input())

if amount > 0:
    try:
        bank[username] += amount
        print(bank)
    except:
        print("There is no one with this username in bank dictionary.")
```

Answer (score -1):

```
bank['John'] += 45
```

You can also use this to simply add another key and value, without using addition.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).